# Socket API :Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, bsd

Hello I have a problem when I am writing the server using the socket api. I always get this error: "Socket operation on non-socket"

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
int port = 10000;
int sd;

memset((char *) &addr,0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = PF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
addr.sin_port = htonl((u_short)port);

if ((sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0)) {

    printf("socket failed");
}

if(bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0)
{
    printf(strerror(errno));
}

close(sd);


return 0;}
```

Comment: If you get an error, (a) don't just print some message of your own devising: use `perror()` or `strerror()`, and (b) don't continue as though the error didn't happen. And it isn't correct to test system calls for `!= 0`: the correct test is `== -1` or `< 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
if ((sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0)) {
```

Doesn't do what you think. If you look closely at the placement of parentheses (and remember that the `<` operator has higher priority than `=`) you will notice that you are actually assigning `sd` the value of the expression `socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) < 0`.

In short, `sd` will most likely end up containing the value 0, because that's what the above expression would normally evaluate to. This explains the "socket operation on non-socket" error; it really isn't a socket.

So the line should read:

```
if ((sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
```

Notice how I shifted a closing parenthesis left by two tokens.

Answer (score 0):

```
addr.sin_port = htonl((u_short)port);
```

should read

```
addr.sin_port = htons((u_short)port);
```

since port is 16bit number.